# how to stop a popup form from preloading on any random click in the wordpress site?

Tags: wordpress, popup, wordpress-theming, contact-form-7, preloading

I'm  using CF7  in my wordpress site, without enter any details,clicking on submit button directly reload without saying to fill required fields,could you please any solution for this issue.

Thank you.

I'm using contact form 7 in WP site, I have all settings,i couldn't find exact solution  for this could u please anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: cf7 is ajax probably you have errors in console ? Without more information we can only use crystal ball

Comment: could u please explain briefly?